# When I add a new mobile app in Bluemix Cloud Foundry, I always get an error

Tags: mobile, ibm-cloud

I am creating a new app in CF mobile but I am getting this error:

```
BXNUI0005E: The 'AlertMe' application could not be added. 
See the Troubleshooting topics in the IBM Bluemix Documentation to 
check service status, review troubleshooting information, 
or for information about getting help.
```

I can't find any related troubleshooting process in the docs.

Comment: What is the app you are trying to create? Do you have a link to the instructions you are following?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the problem occurs when the app name exists already. You have to choose a unique application name.